# Convection Heater Screeches

Tags: electrical, heater, noise

I just recently bought one of those really old Galaxy convection space heaters.  They have always worked so well.  But they screech when they start to heat.  Mind you, this product could very well be 40 or more years old.  Is there any way I can rig it so that it doesn’t screech?  I’m pretty sure it’s the coils making that awful noise and not the fan.

Comment: It probably **is** the fan, and it probably expects to be oiled at the start of heating season. Or else it had "permanently oiled" bearings that have worn out.

Comment: If the sound is more like a 60-Hz buzz combined with a rubbing sound that goes away in **a few seconds** after the coils warm, then there's nothing you need do... that is normal for heaters with coils inside quartz tubes. If there are exposed, wires, you *could* try winding them one turn tighter on the form, at the risk of destroying the heater.

Comment: GREAT INFORMATION.  Thank you!!!